# how to get the current position of the device in a flutter module?

Tags: android, flutter, location, flutter-module

I'm developing A Flutter module for android application, that module use Geolocatore to get the current position of the device. but when the flutter module get initializie I Got this error:

> location_permissions: unable to detect current activity

I have add this two line to AndroidManifest file (for Android app and flutter module two)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I use this function to get the current position

```
 void _getUserLocation() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator()
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    List<Placemark> placemark = await Geolocator()
        .placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    setState(() {
      _initialPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
      _position = position ;
      print('${placemark[0].name}');
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
```

Source  :  [source url](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: @AdilSakout Is the location permission given in the settings of the application?

Comment: No, should the user allow the permission the module get started